.defaultCustomization(.hidden) does not hide toolbar items by default on macOS
I'm writing an app targetting macOS 13 and newer using SwiftUI. It has a toolbar, with some buttons being hidden by default.
I'm trying to use .defaultCustomization(.hidden), as described by Apple docs, to hide these optional buttons.
Unfortunately, this does not work and these buttons are still visible by default
This is my code:
.toolbar(id: "PackageActions")
{
    ToolbarItem(id: "upgradePackagesAction", placement: .primaryAction)
    {
        upgradePackagesButton
    }
    .defaultCustomization(.visible)

    ToolbarItem(id: "addTapAction", placement: .primaryAction)
    {
        addTapButton
    }
    .defaultCustomization(.visible)

    ToolbarItem(id: "installPackageAction", placement: .primaryAction)
    {
        installPackageButton
    }
    .defaultCustomization(.visible)
    
    ToolbarItem(id: "spacer", placement: .secondaryAction)
    {
        Spacer()
    }
    .defaultCustomization(.visible)

    ToolbarItem(id: "maintenanceAction", placement: .secondaryAction)
    {
        performMaintenanceButton
    }
    .defaultCustomization(.hidden)

    ToolbarItem(id: "manageServicesAction", placement: .secondaryAction)
    {
        manageServicesButton
    }
    .defaultCustomization(.hidden)

    ToolbarItem(id: "divider", placement: .automatic)
    {
        Divider()
    }
    .defaultCustomization(.hidden)
}

As you can see, the buttons with IDs maintenanceAction, manageServicesAction and the Divider need to be hidden by default.
Unfortunately, they are not, as can be seen on this screenshot:
I have tried:

Doing the usual cleanup tasks, like cleaning the build folder
Changing the ids of the ToolbarItems


Changing the secondaryActions to primaryAction fixes this for me. Can you do that?

Unfortunately, I can't do that. These are semantically not primary actions
